# Getting 500: Internal Server Error as a response from webserver while sending http request from javascript

Tags: javascript

My code is as follows:

```
    var http_url = ""+MDM_HTTP_URL;

    var httpClient = new A_HttpRequest();
    httpClient.open ("POST", http_url);

    httpClient.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","invokeEPSMDMRTIDealService");
    httpClient.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml");
    httpClient.setRequestHeader("charset","UTF-8");


    var roleObj = Acumen.getRole();
    var userObj = Acumen.getUser();


    var roleName = roleObj.name;
    roleName = roleName.replace(/\&/g,'&amp;');
    print("RAJIV_USER:"+roleName+"\t"+userObj.name+"\t"+userObj.id);


    var soap_request = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:com=\"http://com.cisco.eps.mdm.webservice.xmlSchema\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><com:EPSMDMRTIDealServiceRequest><com:OPTY_NUMBER>"+_DEAL_ID_+"</com:OPTY_NUMBER><com:USER_ID>"+userObj.id+"</com:USER_ID><com:USER_NAME>"+userObj.name+"</com:USER_NAME><com:ROLE>"+roleName+"</com:ROLE></com:EPSMDMRTIDealServiceRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

    var http_response = httpClient.send(soap_request);
    var soapResponse = http_response.getHttpResponseBody();

    print("RESPONSE HEADER IS::\n"+http_response.getHttpResponseHeader());
    print("RESPONSE XML : " +  soapResponse);
    return soapResponse;
```

When i execute the above program, it is giving following output:

```
RESPONSE HEADER IS::
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2013 12:44:00 GMT
Connection: close



RESPONSE XML : <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode></faultcode><faultstring>com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '/' (code 47) in prolog; expected '&lt;'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]</faultstring><detail /></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error means that the server crashed. There's obviously a bug there. Is that server yours?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: check the content of `_DEAL_ID_`, `userObj.id`, `userObj.name` and `roleName`. One of these may contain the `/` character, what the server-side parser complains about. Another guess: delete `<soapenv:Header />` or change it to `<soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>`.